# Error "copy-item : The operation completed successfully" but it worked?

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am trying to run the following step in powershell, which proceeds to error out.  The file is getting copied, so I'm tempted to just workaround it with a Force and an ErrorAction SilentlyContinue. But why is this happening?  It happens regardless of the Force flag, and regardless of the file existing in the target location.

Note that all locations are UNC paths.  Added some extra parts that maybe make a difference(?).

```
$ROOTPATH = "\\servera\sharea"
$STAGEDIR = "$ROOTPATH\submit"

#sample file for $flagfl: 
#-rw-rw-r-- 1 mname data 588573 Aug 31 14:51 file16083101.000.Z

$newfiles = get-content $ROOTPATH\$FLAGFL |  foreach {$_.split(" ")[8]}

foreach ($thisfile in $newfiles) {
$thisfile_unc=($thisfile).Replace('.Z','')
$reccnt = (Get-Content $ROOTPATH\$thisfile_unc | Measure-Object -line).Lines
$orionfile = "$thisfile_unc.$reccnt"

get-content $ROOTPATH\$thisfile_unc |% {$_.replace("`n", "`r`n")} | out-file -encoding ascii -filepath $ROOTPATH\$orionfile -Force

copy-item $ROOTPATH\$orionfile $STAGEDIR -force 
}
```

Error message:

```
copy-item : The operation completed successfully.
At line:1 char:1
+ copy-item $ROOTPATH\$orionfile $STAGEDIR -force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

FULL error message as requested () :

```
Exception             : System.IO.IOException: The operation completed successfully.

                           at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
                           at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean 
                        overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
                           at System.IO.FileInfo.CopyTo(String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.CopyFileInfoItem(FileInfo file, String 
                        destinationPath, Boolean force)
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.CopyItem(String path, String 
                        destinationPath, Boolean recurse)
                           at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.CopyItem(CmdletProvider 
                        providerInstance, String path, String copyPath, Boolean recurse, CmdletProviderContext context)
TargetObject          : 
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

Comment: Wow, another awesome error message to add to the collection. Does the error message still occur if you directly specify the parameter names (`-Path` and `-Destination`) and enclose the paths in quotes (`"$ROOTPATH\$orionfile"` and `"$STAGEDIR"`)?

Comment: Can you include output of `$Error[0] | fl -Force` command after error happened?

Comment: My first hunch is the copy file is right after the file is written. Wonder if a sleep in there would help. Also your code appears incomplete as `$newfiles` is not defined here.

Comment: @Bluecakes still happens.

Comment: @petseral posted above.

Comment: @matt good thought, but I've run the command multiple times, minutes or hours after the file was generated, with the same problem. $newfiles is generated from a split of a file that itself is an "LS" done by the process that puts the file I get on the FTP site.  I'm updating the code example with a sample.

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the same issue, copying from a unc path, but the files weren't generated. They have been there for some time. Powershell version 5.1. For now I'm wrapping it in a try catch and checking the files after the copy to be sure it was successful.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Think I wound up doing a check as well.